# Using ObjectAid in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, objectaid

So I just got ObjectAid for eclipse. 
I created my first UML by placing the classes in the file and arranging them as neatly as I could. I have a few questions regarding its capabilities:

1: Is it able to completely autogenerate a UML for a given a Project? (No user placement)

2: Am I able to include the java libraries that I imported as referenced dependencies? (I am using Swing and would like to notate which classes use which swing classes, etc)

3: Can I change the symbols that the UML generator uses for things such as making public globals '+' and private '-' instead of the nice symbols

4: Are these symbols considered standard?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: mostly yes, user should choose what to include in the UML(visibility, relations...), and for example when generating class diagrams you will have to place all the objects in order to make it more understandable.

2: you should right click the class and select add->generalized

3: when creating the class diagram you should unselect the option "show icons" and then you will see the '+' and '-' symbols and no other icons

4: the most used standards are '+', '-', '#'... I don't know if those icons are standard because I always use it without icons.

Hope I solved your doubts

Comment: Is it possible to change the resolution, text size, etc... for a class diagram in object aid? I simply would like to fit more stuff in the screen than normally possible as installed.